# Resolving resources from one UserControl to a parent UserControl

Tags: wpf, user-controls, resources

I've got a user control UserControl1, which defines a style in its resources. That user control contains an instance of UserControl2, which references that style:

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControl1">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="MyStyle" />
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <UserControl2 />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>

<UserControl x:Class="UserControl2">
    <Grid Style="{StaticResource MyStyle}">
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

However, UserControl2 cannot find that style resource, even though it is in the logical tree (within the resources of UserControl1). How can I get UserControl2 to find the resources in UserControl1?

Comment: Is there a specific reason that style sits inside the UserControl and not in a ResourceDictionary?

Comment: It actually is in a resourcedictionary, but I'm including it in MergeDictionaries of UserControl1. This is because it contains some theme-like styles that I only want applied to UserControl1 and everything hanging off it.

Comment: Then how bout exposing a new Dependency Property in UserControl2 which will allow you to set the template from outside?

Comment: That would work, but there's multiple layers of usercontrols and many, many styles. Exposing a property for all of them is not practicable.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it but, but I would suggest using a `ResourceDictionary` instead.

Anyway, if you want to do it this way you can use `FindAncestor` to find the parent and access the `Resource` you want out of the Parent `ResourceDictionary`

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControl1">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="MyStyle" />
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <UserControl2 />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>

<UserControl x:Class="UserControl2">
    <Grid Style="{Binding Resources[MyStyle], RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:UserControl1}}}">
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Beacause `Resource` is a dictionary you can access using the `key` just like in code behind

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and was able to solve it by referencing the resource through `DynamicResource` instead of `StaticResource`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControl2">
    <Grid Style="{DynamicResource MyStyle}">
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The compiler does still give a warning that the resource cannot be resolved.